# How to export/download audit summary records for a Dataverse table into an Excel workbook or as a CSV?

Tags: powerapps, audit-trail, dataverse, power-platform, xrmtoolbox

I am looking for a way to export/download audit summary records for one of my Dataverse tables in form of an Excel workbook or as a CSV.

I've checked if 'Audit History Explorer' plugin for XRMToolBox provides any way to download it but couldn't find any solution there.
Does there exist any way to do this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Audit History Extractor in XRMToolbox

Comment: Yes, it's possible using audit history extractor tool in XRMToolBox. I was earlier not able to locate and install the tool but have figured it out now. Thanks.